# Compare 2 csv files on databricks using pyspark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am having some trouble finding a good way to compare two csv files using databricks, so here's the gist of it:

I have two ddbb that are supossed to have exactly the same information (spoiler: they don't) and both of them have a process that creates 4 csv files with info on different things that are the ones that we need to compare.

My first thought was to make a left anti join to take out all the rows that are not in one of the dfs, then I moved on to using exceptAll since it seems to do the same. With this I gathered all of the rows that are on df2 but not in df1 and viceversa, this gives me too many rows to manage, so I am wondering if theres a way to compare row by row and keeping the differences between rows with, for example, the same name surname and birthdate or similar things that identify a specific subject on the dataframe.

Thank you all in advance for helping me out with this.

Comment: How do you know which row from the first file should be compared with which row from the second file. Is there something like a "primary key" that can be used to match the rows? Could you share some example data?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this function that works quite well for anyone that might have the same problem:

```
def find_mismatch(df1, df2, key_list):
  
  def is_mismatch(col):
    values = (df1[col] != df2[col]) 
    return values | (df1[col].isNull() & df2[col].isNotNull()) | (df1[col].isNotNull() & df2[col].isNull())
  
  result = df1.join(df2, key_list, "outer")
  
  # Selecting original columns from both DataFrames
  select_columns = [result[i] for i in key_list]
  
  for col in df1.columns:
    if col not in key_list:
      select_columns.extend([
          df1[col].alias(col + '_df1'),
          df2[col].alias(col + '_df2'),
          is_mismatch(col).alias(col + '_mismatch')
      ])
  
  result = result.select(*select_columns)
  
  mismatched_cols = result.where(
      reduce(lambda acc, e: acc | e, [result[c + '_mismatch'] for c in df1.columns if c not in key_list], F.lit(False))
  )
  mismatch_count = mismatched_cols.count()
  return mismatch_count, mismatched_cols
```